How to get the first struct from a queue that is made up of many structs which can't be copied but can be moved?
The struct contains a std::promise<std::any> so it can't be constructed by a copy constructor. But it can't run correctly yet even I provided Move constructors and move assignors. And it reported three errors:
static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
无法引用 函数 "test::test(const test &other)" (已声明 所在行数:19) -- 它是已删除的函数
use of deleted function 'test::test(const test&)'
Code to reproduce:
#include <future>
#include <any>
#include <queue>

struct test{
    std::promise<std::any> p;

    test()=default;
    test(test&& other){
        p = std::move(other.p);
    }

    test& operator=(test&& other){
        p = std::move(other.p);
        return *this;
    }

    test& operator=(const test& other)=delete;
    test(const test& other)=delete;
};

test getFirst(std::queue<test> tests){
    test test = tests.front();
    tests.pop();
    return test;
}

int main(){
    test t;
    std::queue<test> tests;
    test t2 = getFirst(tests);
    return 0;
}


test getFirst(std::queue<test> &tests) {  // (1)
  test test = std::move(tests.front());   // (2)
  tests.pop();
  return test;
}

Two issues were in your code.

You got std::queue<test> tests by copy.
tests.front() returned a reference that could be moved.


Thanks!Your help is like a light in the dark to me!

You made a nice [mre], it was easy to copy and then fix the code.
